# Can you get SkinID Autocompletion in ASCX Controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, autocomplete, skin, web-user-controls

Working in VS 2008

When working on on ASPX file in `Source` mode, if i've specified a StyleSheetTheme in the page directive of the file, then Visual Studio will provide me with AutoCompletion lists of the possible skinID values for a control

e.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" SkinID="
//Having typed this much, I'll get an intellisense with the possible skinid values for this button
```

I'm just wondering is it possible to get the same functionality in an ASCX.
Because theres no stylesheettheme specified for the control, VS doesn't know what the possible values are...

**Can you specify a default stylesheet theme that Visual Studio can use for Web User Controls.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. If you specify a default theme in your web.config, then the available skins will also be listed by intellsense in user controls.

To define a default theme, edit the following entry in web.config:

```
...
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages styleSheetTheme="MyTheme">
    ...
```

This works for both Themes and StyleSheetThemes. But it may take some time (or a rebuild?) until the available skins are listed by intellisense.

BTW: specifying the theme to be used in web.config (instead of in the pages) has the additional advantage, that you can very easily switch themes.